# AWS Cognito Hosted UI Bypasses WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, access-control-list, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 hosted site behind a Cloudfront and WAF.  I set up a Cognito hosted UI with a custom domain (auth.example.com where example.com is my site).  Cognito generates a Cloudfront distribution that is aliased in Route 53 to my domain but doesn't appear listed as an option under Add Resources to WAF ACL.  As a result I can't add the hosted UI pages to my WAF.

How do I get the hosted UI behind the WAF ?

Comment: How would you expect your WAF to interact with S3?  S3 should be static pages, and a WAF is normally used to protect against attacks such as XSS and SQLi

Comment: The S3 static pages are protected by the WAF.  It's the Cognito hosted UI I'd like to also protect under the same WAF.